# Style tags in angular 7 app, where are they from

Tags: angular

Hi I've been digging and searching to find out where style tags are coming from in an angular application. When I run ng serve and look at the source I can see a bunch of style tags with style information. However, I don't know where this is coming from [image]

How do i work out which files contains these styles ?

NB: I've used VSCode's search feature to search key words, but I wasn't able to locate the file.

Comment: They are coming from components or angular.json styles

Answer (score 0):

Angular resolves your .scss files and the .css/.scss files of your included libraries (e.g. in the `styles` array of your angular.json file) and copies them into the compiled index.html file.

Please refer to the following [article](https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975) about how angular cli webpack delivers your css styles to the client.

Comment: The link got broken :/